# Is the Nashbar Fluid Trainer loud?

Tags: road-bike, trainer

I am trying to find out how loud the Nashbar Fluid Trainer is, as I don't know anyone who owns one. How loud is it, compared to other, similar trainers?

Comment: What would you consider loud? Using any trainer will be noisy. You are right, the fluid and magnetic trainers will be quieter than the wind resistance trainers.

Comment: Left a clarification in the question. @runxc1, please revert my edit if I'm off-base here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used one, but judging from what I've been able to [find on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jI4Mw1CIUDc), they are definitely quieter than the magnetic trainers I have at home.